# convert string arrayList to Integer ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, android-recyclerview

**I have Model class ModelWeeklyGuarantee That  want to convert string arrayList to integer arrayList**

Example [5,7,9] string arrayList, to IntegerArrayList [5,7,8] at index 0.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> listOfGuarantees= new ArrayList<Integer>();
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelWeeklyGuarantee ModelGuarantee = GauranteeList.get(position);

    JSONArray jsonArray = ModelGuarantee.getWeeklyDataList();
    Log.d("getWeeklyDataList",""+jsonArray);
    for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Integer abc= Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.toString());
            listOfGuarantees.add( Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.toString()));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("guaranteevalues",""+listOfGuarantees);
    }
```

getWeeklyDataList: ["5","7","9"]

getWeeklyDataList: ["10","11","12"]

guaranteevalues=[]

> org.json.JSONException: Value 5 at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Comment: Error message says that you are trying to cast `"5"` to a `JSONObject`, which is impossible. What is not clear for you?

Comment: yes brother i want to store whole string [5,7,9] as INTEGER in listOfGuarantees ArrayList at index 0

Comment: Have you read my comment? `What is not clear for you?`

Comment: yes i am facing problem to store [5,7,9] stringArrayList as IntegerArrayList

Comment: ok, do you know what is the JsonObject? Do you know that `"5"` is clearly not a valid JsonObject? Why do you try to convert `"5"` to a JsonObject at all? Why don't you just get is as an Integer?

Comment: @VladMatvienko i have jsonArray getWeeklyDataList [5,7,9]

Comment: and want to save getWeeklyDataList as integer array

Comment: I know that, you already told that for 3 times. Just check other methods of `jsonArray.`, you will find a method, which will get you an Integer instead of JsonObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hold string to json object.

Replace this line

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
listOfGuarantees.add( Integer.valueOf(jsonObject.toString()));
```

with

```
String obj = jsonArray.getString(i); 
listOfGuarantees.add( Integer.valueOf(obj));
```

Or Simply use

```
listOfGuarantees.add(Integer.valueOf(jsonArray.getString(i)));
```

**EDIT/UPDATED**

```
ArrayList<int[]> listOfGuarantees= new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[] values;
JSONArray jsonArray = ModelGuarantee.getWeeklyDataList();
Log.d("getWeeklyDataList",""+jsonArray);
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    values = new int[] { count };
    try 
    {
        String str = jsonArray.getString(i);
        values[i] = Integer.valueOf(str); 
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("guaranteevalues",""+listOfGuarantees);
}
 listOfGuarantees.add(values);
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Mohaideen
Array Type Expected ;Found ORG.json.jsonArray

Comment: Try this String str = jsonArray.getString(i); listOfGuarantees.add( Integer.valueOf(str));

Comment: it will store 
0 index [5]
1 index [7]
2 index [9]

but i want [5,7,9] at 0 index

Comment: i cant mean what you are saying explain.

Comment: I want to store whole string arrayObject as integer object

Comment: simply add index for array while adding items in array like listOfGuarantees.add(0,Integer.valueOf(jsonArray.getString(i))); //0 is index value

Comment: You mean you want string array  ["5","7","9"],["10","11","12"] to integer array [579,101112]

Comment: no i want ["5","7","9"],["10","11","12"]  to integer array [5,7,9],[10,11,12]

Comment: so you have to create multidimensional array. integer array inside integer array.

Comment: brother how i would do this?

Comment: First change your intial array declration from  ArrayList<Integer> listOfGuarantees= new ArrayList<Integer>(); to ArrayList<Integer[]> listOfGuarantees= new ArrayList<Integer[]>(); then you can add values to integer[].

Comment: values = new array[count];
                values.add(Integer.valueOf(jsonArray.getString(i)));

Here new array and values.add cannot resolved

Comment: change values = new array[count]; to  values = new int[] { count }; then add values[i] = Integer.valueOf(jsonArray.getString(i));.. See my updated answer.